# 2 consoles, 2 players with 2 homes, 1 Island

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Can 2 players, each with their own console and game card, using WiFi or local play, live on the same island with separate homes?

My daughter and I play, sometimes at the same time, sometimes not. We both want to make layout changes. I have a Switch Lite, and she has a Switch with detachable controllers.
We have two game cards but I’m happy to purchase the other version if need to. We share a Nintendo account.

Answer (score 2):

No.  AC:NH islands are tied to individual Switches.  One Switch = one island; an island cannot be shared between two Switches.

The closest thing you can do is visit each others' islands while both players are online, though the visitor's home does not come with them, and they cannot make changes to the host island.